# dataclass how to edit list

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I have a dataclass set up like so:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class stats:
   foo: List[list] = field(default_factory=list)
```

I tried to edit the contents of the list by using

`stats().foo = [[1], [1]]`

This did nothing. How can I change the contents of the list?

Comment: you're modifying the instance attribute of `foo` not the class attribute. since you are not binding `stats()` to a variable, nothing happens overall beyond that line

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part that is missing from you code is the instance creation & assigning to a variable.
The below is creating an instance of `stats` named `s`.
After `s` is created you can populate `foo` or do anything you want with `s` data members or methods

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

@dataclass
class stats:
   foo: List[list] = field(default_factory=list)

s = stats()
s.foo = [[1], [1]]
print(s)
```

Another option is to use `__init__` in order to populate the instance:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List


@dataclass
class stats:
    foo: List[list] = field(default_factory=list)

s = stats(['A', 'B'])
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
class stats:
    foo: list[int] = field(default_factory=list)

c = stats()
c.foo += [[1], [1]]
```

We can add List content by taking a variable like c in this example, then assign this variable to your class name. Now You can add content by simply adding list content as shown.

for more [visit here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html)

Comment: the issue OP is facing has _nothing_ to do with dataclasses and everything to do with class/instances. you should explain why their code does not work.

Comment: understood, will take care next time.

Comment: you answered this question so you should explain on this question, not next time...